# SQL query in Excel table

Tags: sql, select

I am running a query using `OleDbCommand` in a database in Excel, containing the following columns:

```
name, city, inhabitants
```

My code:

```
 Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
 Cmd.Connection = Conn;
 Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
 Cmd.CommandText = "Select City, count(habitants) as h from [Sheet1$] where city = @city group by city";
 var Reader = await Cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

I get this error:

> OleDbException: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'city' as part of an aggregate function.

Why does this error appear if it contains the city column?

Comment: I added the group by and still continue with error

Answer (score 0):

You can probably work around this error by adding `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "Select City, count(habitants) as h from [Sheet1$] where city=@city group by City";
```

Comment: I am surprised this did not fix your problem.  Are you certain you ran the exact query in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FIRST()` function for the `city`:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FIRST(city) AS city, COUNT(habitants) AS h FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE city=@city GROUP BY city";
```